# Multiple user accounts from same client on network share?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, user-accounts, smb

My Win7 professional client has a connected network drive to the server with cached login (user/pw) data. How can I connect to the same server as a different user simultaneously?

Comment: For anyone still dealing with this problem, take a look here: [http://superuser.com/a/403260/321001](http://superuser.com/a/403260/321001) that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Map network drives to the same location using different credentials.

Or

Try this: net use \fullPathToShare /u:username “password” and take a look at this KB article: support.microsoft.com/kb/938120

Comment: I must map a 2nd network drive?

Comment: Yes; that is one easy way to do it.

Comment: If I could, I'd like to avoid that.