# New samba user won't login

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba

I've already got one samba user setup on my Arch desktop computer that is used by all the computers running Windows on my home network for sharing files. Here's the samba share configuration:

```
[Shared Documents]
path = /home/shared
comment = Access to shared documents
valid users = samba
read only = no
browseable = yes
writable = yes
vfs object = recycle
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:versions = yes
recycle:repository = /home/shared/Recycle Bin
recycle:touch_mtime = yes
recycle:exclude = *.tmp, *.bak
recycle:exclude_dir = "Recycle Bin"
```

..it works fine.

I wanted to add another shared user and share specifically for the Windows computers to save backups to.

Here's the share configuration:

```
[Backups]
path = /home/backups
comment = Backups
valid users = backups
read only = no
browseable = no
writable = yes
```

..and here's how I setup the user:

```
sudo useradd backups
sudo passwd backups
sudo smbpasswd -a backups
sudo vim /etc/samba/smbusers
sudo systemctl restart smbd nmbds
```

I set both passwords the same, and added this to `/etc/samba/smbusers`:

```
backups =  backups
```

Finally, I created the directory `/home/backups` and ran `sudo chown backups backups`.

Whenever I try to access the share on a computer running Windows 8.1, I get the following error:

[image: Windows error]

Running `sudo pdbedit -L -v` gives a similar output for both users:

```
---------------
Unix username:        samba
NT username:          
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-2291605615-1340112646-1700999338-1002
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-2291605615-1340112646-1700999338-513
Full Name:            
Home Directory:       \\arctic\samba
HomeDir Drive:        
Logon Script:         
Profile Path:         \\arctic\samba\profile
Domain:               ARCTIC
Account desc:         
Workstations:         
Munged dial:          
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          Wed, 06 Feb 2036 15:06:39 GMT
Kickoff time:         Wed, 06 Feb 2036 15:06:39 GMT
Password last set:    Thu, 03 Oct 2013 19:23:55 BST
Password can change:  Thu, 03 Oct 2013 19:23:55 BST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
---------------
```

---

```
---------------
Unix username:        backups
NT username:          
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-2291605615-1340112646-1700999338-1008
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-2291605615-1340112646-1700999338-513
Full Name:            
Home Directory:       \\arctic\backups
HomeDir Drive:        
Logon Script:         
Profile Path:         \\arctic\backups\profile
Domain:               ARCTIC
Account desc:         
Workstations:         
Munged dial:          
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          Wed, 06 Feb 2036 15:06:39 GMT
Kickoff time:         Wed, 06 Feb 2036 15:06:39 GMT
Password last set:    Sat, 26 Oct 2013 12:27:45 BST
Password can change:  Sat, 26 Oct 2013 12:27:45 BST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
---------------
```

The logs show this:

```
[2013/10/26 13:11:14.149343,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:550(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

---

If I modify the configuration to allow the user `samba` to access backups and restart samba, the Windows client can connect with any issues.

What have I done wrong..?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I was able to connect on a computer that hadn't connected to either shares before, and this worked.

Then I discovered that the error message actually said multiple connections are forbidden. I neglected to read this previously, only reading the top half.

To work around this, I have used an address that points to my home network.

Also see [Samba+Windows: Allow multiple connections by different users?](https://superuser.com/questions/95872/sambawindows-allow-multiple-connections-by-different-users).